# Infragistics UltraValidator

Tags: c#, infragistics

I am using infragistics UltraValidator. I wana remove the text "validation failed with the following error(s)" from validate message box or need to set custom message. please help me out.

Regards
Anfil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the error message displayed through the `ValidationSettings` properties located in the general properties of the control that fails the validation.

There you can find the properties `Caption` and `Text` that you can change as you like. (as well other properties that allow to configure individual behavior on a single control basis)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Sorry to say that my real issue still exist. ie. while Validate() method is executed, in message box a caption "Validation failed with the following error(s)" is displayed. I need to remove this message.

Will be very helpful if u reply for this.
Regards
ANFIL

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce your problem. I suppose you have already checked your code if this string is present somewhere. I suggest to remove temporarily the UltraValidator and check if the message is still present (Just to rule out different causes)

Comment: Thanks for the response.
As i am unable to post the code here. i opened a new Question forum.
please check the link, expecting your valuable reply.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715432/infragistics-ultravalidator-new

Comment: Thanks. The problem is solved in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715432/infragistics-ultravalidator-new