# Infragistics UltraValidator new

Tags: c#, infragistics

I am using infragistics UltraValidator. I want to remove the text "validation failed with the following error(s)" from validate message box. please help me out

HERE IS THE CODE >>

```
private void uValidate_ValidationError(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e){

        Infragistics.Win.Misc.ValidationSettings settings;
            settings = this.uValidate.GetValidationSettings( UltraTextEditor );
            settings.NotificationSettings.Action = Infragistics.Win.Misc.NotificationAction.MessageBox;
            settings.NotificationSettings.Caption = "Required Fields";
            settings.NotificationSettings.Text = "Select Customer";
    }


bool ValidateMyControls()
    {
        Infragistics.Win.Misc.Validation v = uValidate.Validate();

        return v.IsValid;
    }
```

uValidate is UltraValidator control

when the method ValidateMyControls() is triggered, I will get a message box, with a string on top "Validation failed with the following error(s):". This string i need to remove or edit.

Regards
Anfil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I understand what's happening here.
You need to customize the resource string identified by:

```
"Validate_ErrorNotificationMessageHeader"
```

This is an internal string contained in the resources of the `Infragistics.Win.Misc` assembly and it is displayed automatically by the assembly before your message "Select Customer".

You could customize the string with the following instruction

```
ResourceCustomizer rc = Infragistics.Win.Misc.Resources.Customizer;
rc.SetCustomizedString("Validate_ErrorNotificationMessageHeader", "Your message here");
```

Every Infragistics assembly has a list of strings that can be customized in this way.
For a complete list of the resource strings available [look here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Win_Assembly_Resource_Strings.html). (And this is only for WinForms).
The best method to handle this task is to create a generic method called just one time at the startup of your application (Something like `GlobalAppUtility.SetInfragisticsResourceStrings()`; )

Comment: Thanks alot for your timely response.
Now its working perfectly.